# EditText in ListView have repeating cursor position android

Tags: android

I have a listview in which it has an edittext. When I click on first position of edittext and write something on that, the same text is written in another edittext of same field id of edittext in different position of the listview.

I have been stuck in this for last 12 hours. I have tried to search every where but I haven't found any answers for this.

[image]

here is my adapter class code

public class AttendanceSheetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
Activity activity;
LayoutInflater inflater;
String trip, vehicleNo, msg;
ArrayList<Datalist> datalists;
int a;
boolean b;

public AttendanceSheetAdapter(Activity activity, int resource, ArrayList<Datalist> datalists) {
    super(activity, resource, datalists);
    this.activity = activity;
    this.datalists = datalists;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return datalists.size();
}

@Override
public Datalist getItem(int position) {
    return datalists.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.attendance_adapter, null);

    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.vehicleId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.vehicleId);
    holder.tripId = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tripId);
    holder.comments = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.comments);
    holder.driverPhoto = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.driverPhoto);

    Datalist d = datalists.get(position);
    d.getVehicleNo();
    d.getDriverPhoto();

    holder.vehicleId.setText(d.vehicleNo);
    holder.driverName.setText(d.getDriverName());
    if (holder.driverPhoto != null) {
        Picasso.with(activity).load(d.getDriverPhoto()).into(holder.driverPhoto);
    }
    holder.comments.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            msg = arg0.toString();
        }
    });
    holder.comments.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                if (a == position) {
                    if (msg != null) {
                        msg = msg.replace(" ", "%20");
                        vehicleNo = datalists.get(position).getVehicleNo();
                        COMMENTS(); // api call
                    }
                }
            }
            if (a != position && b != false) {
                if (trip != null) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), AttendanceSheet.class);
                    activity.startActivity(i);
                    activity.finish();
                }
            }
            a = position;
            b = true;
        }
    });

    holder.tripId.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

            trip = arg0.toString();
        }
    });
    holder.tripId.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {


            if (!hasFocus) {
                if (a == position) {
                    if (trip != null) {
                        trip = trip.replace(" ", "%20");
                        vehicleNo = datalists.get(position).getVehicleNo();
                        TRIPID(); // api call
                    }
                }
            }
            if (a != position && b != false) {
                if (trip != null) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), AttendanceSheet.class);
                    activity.startActivity(i);
                    activity.finish();
                }
            }
            a = position;
            b = true;
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView vehicleId;
    EditText comments, tripId;
    ImageView driverPhoto;
}
```

}

Comment: always post code with question , people discourage by dislike question.....

Comment: We can't help you if you don't show and explain your code.

Comment: Can you post your List Adapter file??

Comment: Post.Your.Code. Especially the part where you populate your List.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code Try to use below Code and check if it works:

```
    Activity activity;
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        String trip, vehicleNo, msg;
        ArrayList<Datalist> datalists;
        int a;
        boolean b;

        public AttendanceSheetAdapter(Activity activity, int resource, ArrayList<Datalist> datalists) {
            super(activity, resource, datalists);
            this.activity = activity;
            this.datalists = datalists;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return datalists.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Datalist getItem(int position) {
            return datalists.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

            if (inflater == null)
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null){
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.attendance_adapter, parent,false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.vehicleId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.vehicleId);
            holder.tripId = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tripId);
            holder.comments = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.comments);
            holder.driverPhoto = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.driverPhoto);
convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{

    holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
            Datalist d = datalists.get(position);
            d.getVehicleNo();
            d.getDriverPhoto();

            holder.vehicleId.setText(d.vehicleNo);
            holder.driverName.setText(d.getDriverName());
            if (holder.driverPhoto != null) {
                Picasso.with(activity).load(d.getDriverPhoto()).into(holder.driverPhoto);
            }
            holder.comments.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                    msg = arg0.toString();
                }
            });
            holder.comments.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    if (!hasFocus) {
                        if (a == position) {
                            if (msg != null) {
                                msg = msg.replace(" ", "%20");
                                vehicleNo = datalists.get(position).getVehicleNo();
                                COMMENTS(); // api call
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (a != position && b != false) {
                        if (trip != null) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), AttendanceSheet.class);
                            activity.startActivity(i);
                            activity.finish();
                        }
                    }
                    a = position;
                    b = true;
                }
            });

            holder.tripId.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

                    trip = arg0.toString();
                }
            });
            holder.tripId.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {


                    if (!hasFocus) {
                        if (a == position) {
                            if (trip != null) {
                                trip = trip.replace(" ", "%20");
                                vehicleNo = datalists.get(position).getVehicleNo();
                                TRIPID(); // api call
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (a != position && b != false) {
                        if (trip != null) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), AttendanceSheet.class);
                            activity.startActivity(i);
                            activity.finish();
                        }
                    }
                    a = position;
                    b = true;
                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView vehicleId;
            EditText comments, tripId;
            ImageView driverPhoto;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is happening when you changed the code?? Same issue or something else?

Comment: same issue came, its changing nothing